# How to store the role of a user from database in a session and compare it for redirect in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I created a login with sessions in PHP using MySQL. I want to separate the user from admin, but I don't know how to get the role from the database and where should I store it in session, or compare it for later usage?

I tried some tips/solutions from different answers, but I use PDO and I didn't manage to fix my problem.

Here's my code:

index.php

Here I want to check if the user is already set in session and compare the role. If the role is admin redirect to admin.php else profile.php

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Profile Page
}
?>
// + html for login form
```

login.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error = ''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else{
    // Define $username and $password
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin", "daw2");
    $query = "SELECT email, password from user where email=? AND password=? LIMIT 1";
    // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($email, $password);
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row
{
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $email; // Initializing Session
    header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Profile Page
}
mysqli_close($conn); // Closing Connection
}
?>
```

After I prepare $query how can I get the role from db and store it in session?
I need to do something like $_SESSION['login_user']['role'] or ?

session.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin", "daw2");
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$query = "SELECT email from user where email = '$user_check'";
$ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session = $row['email'];
?>
```